# error using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use the pandas package for python. Some functionalities work, but when I try to pass "include" argument into the describe() function I get an error:

```
train_df.describe(include=['O'])
```

Full code looks like thie following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import random as rnd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

# aquire data
train_df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
test_df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

train_df.describe(include=['O'])
```

I get the following error:

```
>> python survival.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "survival.py", line 10, in <module>
train_df.describe(include=['O'])
TypeError: describe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include'
```

Using the .describe() on its own seems to work. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: what version of `pandas` are you using?  `pd.__version__`

Comment: 0.13.1 according pd.__version__. I'm using python 2.7.6 and installed pandas via ubuntu (sudo apt-get install python-pandas)

Comment: `include` was not added as a parameter until version 0.15.0, so you'll need to upgrade your version of pandas if you want to use `include`.

Comment: ah, it's a version issue. thank you for the help!